# Initializer element is not constant in C compiler

Tags: c

I'm trying to do this outside any function and I get : Initializer element is not constant.

What can I do?

```
typedef struct color
{
  const uint8_t alpha;
  const uint8_t red;
  const uint8_t green;
  const uint8_t blue;
}COLOR;

COLOR RED   = {0xF, 15, 0, 0};
COLOR GREEN = {0xF, 0, 15, 0};
COLOR BLUE =  {0xF, 0, 0, 15};

uint8_t alpha = RED.alpha;
uint8_t red   = RED.red;
uint8_t green = RED.green;
uint8_t blue  = RED.green;
```

Thanks!

Comment: `const COLOR RED = { ... };` ?

Comment: @NateEldredge doesn't do the trick...

Comment: It does [here](https://godbolt.org/z/dYcTqorcc), but perhaps it's a GCC extension.

Comment: It's a STM32F Compiler

Comment: Constant expressions are fairly restrictive in C.  In particular, they can't reference variables, regardless of whether the referenced variable is declared `const`.  Your best bet might be to use macros for the color values.

Comment: `It's a STM32F Compiler` nothing like this exists. I know at least 5 compilers that generate code for STM32F series uCs

Comment: Some other compilers allow compound literals, so you could do `#define RED ((COLOR){0xF, 15, 0, 0})`, ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/3dq536EY6)), but it doesn't seem to be standard and GCC rejects it.

Comment: `const` is a confusing keyword. Stroustrup's original proposal was `readonly`. `const` is more confusing because it doesn't make something a constant expression as C understands it (integer literals, expressions consisting solely of those, macros referring there to, enums + most `sizeof`s). In fact, a const qualified object can never be a constant expression.

Comment: @NateEldredge: `#define RED ((COLOR){0xF, 15, 0, 0})` is valid in C99 and later — but it is a 'compound literal' which is variable, and hence it still can't be used in global scope initializers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Right.  But clang appears to allow it in global initializers (as an extension, I suppose).

Comment: @NateEldredge: interesting — extensions are almost always problematic, especially if used unintentionally.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's also interesting that clang accepts it even with `-pedantic`.  That could be a bug.

Comment: @NateEldredge: `-Wpedantic-errors`?  Sometimes that works differently from just `-pedantic` — I've not tested it.

Answer (score -1):

Static storage object initializers have to to be constant expressions. Constant objects or constant struct members are not constant expressions in C.

What is constant expression:

> ### 6.9 Constant Expressions
>
> A constant expression is an expression that contains only constants. A constant expression can be evaluated during compilation rather than at run time, and can be used in any place that a constant can occur. In the following example, limit+1 is a constant expression, and is evaluated at compile time:
>
> ```
> #define limit 500
> char x[limit+1];
> ```
>
> A constant expression cannot contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are within the operand of a sizeof operator. Each constant expression must evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for its type.
>
> There are several contexts in which C requires an expression that must evaluate to a constant:
>
> - The size of a bit field
> - The value of an enumeration constant
> - The size of an array (and the second and subsequent dimensions in all array declarations)
> - The value of a case label
> - An integral constant expression used in conditional-inclusion preprocessing directives
> - The initializer list for an object with static storage duration
>
> #### 6.9.1 Integral Constant Expressions
>
> An integral constant expression has an integral type and contains only operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof expressions, or floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operands in an integral constant expression only convert arithmetic types to integral types, except as part of an operand to the sizeof operator.
>
> C allows more latitude for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant expression can evaluate to one of the following:
>
> - An arithmetic constant expression
> - A null pointer constant
> - An address constant
> - An address constant for an object type plus or minus an integral constant expression
>
> #### 6.9.2 Arithmetic Constant Expressions
>
> An arithmetic constant expression has an arithmetic type and contains only operands that are integer constants, floating constants, enumeration constants, character constants, or sizeof expressions. Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression only convert arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of an operand to the sizeof operator.
>
> #### 6.9.3 Address Constants
>
> An address constant is a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration (see Section 2.10), or to a function designator. Address constants must be created explicitly by using the unary `&` operator, or implicitly by using an expression of array or function type. The array subscript `[]` and member access operators `.` and `->`, the address `&` and indirection `*` unary operators, and pointer casts can be used to create an address constant, but the value of an object cannot be accessed by use of these operators.

The above from: https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_066.HTM

Comment: Note that the section number §6.9 shown does not correspond to a section in the C standard. In C99, C11, and C18, it is [§6.6 Constant expressions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6) without any sub-sections.  And this matters because the rule "The size of an array (and the second and subsequent dimensions in all array declarations)" doesn't apply in C99 or later.  The quote was not directly a part of the C90 standard either (and the section was §6.4 Constant expressions in C90), but the rule applied in C90 — there were no variable-length arrays as understood in C99 and later.